# Removing blue border in <form> submit button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the small blue border around my submit button which appears when it's pressed. I tried to fix it with `border: none;` but that didnt fix it.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hover.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="button1" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="ORANGE" 
                class="btn btn-warning"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va4cntoo/)
I'm using XAMPP to run it on localhost and Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90

**UPDATE**

---

```
.btn:focus {
      outline: none;
}
```

This fixed it for me! I do not not plan on making my site accessible via keyboard so I do not need the blue outline. It's just for looks.

Comment: Jsfiddle code looks fine for me. There is no blue border.

Comment: Which browser did you use?

Comment: Are you talking about the outline when you click on the button? This is what your button looks like on Chrome https://www.evernote.com/shard/s136/sh/b17e198f-8c77-4306-9a81-c2a902b139ca/20a74b16b9bc85451e507e459ad95041

Comment: Yes the border that appears when the button is pressed. Do you know of a way to remove it for Chrome?

Comment: Use the `outline: none;` method that some others have described in their answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<style>   
 .btn:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

Add the above styles inside `head` tag.
By default, bootstrap have outline color blue for focused buttons.
You can remove/update it using class "btn" like mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

> As @MatthewRapati suggested: This outline let's people know that the
>   button has focus and should not be removed. It is an accessibility
>   concern. It is better to restyle it if the default is not wanted

Comment: This outline let's people know that the button has focus and **should not** be removed. It is an accessibility concern. It is better to restyle it if the default is not wanted.

Comment: Yes, agreed @MatthewRapati but the question is about removing it :P

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "outline" from the button on click (a:focus)

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Outline are primarily used for accessibility settings, and should be retained for default behavior unless you are providing some mechanism or highlight for focus/accessibility. If you simply remove without providing the same and user uses Keyboard to navigate, he will not be able to know what link/button he is currently on and may ruin the overall experience with your page.**

Remove the outline from button

```
.btn-warning:focus{
    outline:0px;
}
```

You can also remove outline from all the buttons using

```
input[type=button]:focus,input[type=submit]:focus{
    outline:0px;
}
```

Default button focus has outline of 1px blue on Chrome. There are many more items which have outline, you can disable all of them using:

```
*{
    outline:0px;
}
```

Comment: Please never actually do this.

Comment: Why should I not do it like suggested?

Comment: @Aruloci anyone using a keyboard to navigate your site won't know what element has focus. They won't know where they are.

Comment: @MatthewRapati, but the OP wants to know how to remove this and what is that border. Accessibility settings are individual websites preference. He may like to highlight differently on focus, outline is not the only option.

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary yes, of course, but I imagine that the OP or anyone reading this question for answers could likely not know why these outlines are used and just simply remove them for aesthetics.

Comment: @MatthewRapati Added a kind of information in answer so anyone reading them also knows the uses and consequences. :)

Answer (score 1):

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/baqunkn1/

```
.btn-warning {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff851b;
  border-color: #ff7701;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
}
```